# Why can't Naruto transform into the Nine Tails?

Tags: naruto

Killer B is able to transform into the 8 tails at will and be in control as he befriended the 8 tails.

[image: Eight tails transformation by B].

Naruto has befriended the 9 tails too, but we never saw him transform into the Nine Tails like he did when he was fighting Pain and lost control of the Nine Tails (made of bones and muscles).

[image: Nine Tails With flesh and bones]

Now all we get to see him transform into is a kind of Susanoo like Nine Tails cloak.

[image: Naruto's Transformation]

Why doesn't he transform into the actual Nine Tails(made of flesh and bones like in picture below)?[image: The Nine Tails]

Comment: It is duo to kuramas significance, it is the strongest of the tailed beasts and the chakra nature is somewhat more intense than the others. if you think about it minato also has his transformation like naruto does. when naruto was fighting pain the tailed beast got free and out of control and wanted to devour naruto. so the bones and muscles began to form, but when naruto is in control the chakra behavior changes. hence the change in appearance

Comment: @Henjin Killer B is in control when he transforms but his transformation still has flesh and bones, but now that Naruto has befriended the 9 tails, he should be able to do the flesh and bones transformation right? The difference between the 8 and 9 tails is not as high as the other tailed beasts

Comment: I've added pictures to make my question clearer. My question is: Why doesn't Naruto transform into the Nine Tails like the last picture?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6050/why-is-narutos-jinchuriki-transformation-so-different), which relates to [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3314/why-do-kurama-and-gyuki-appear-as-chakra-while-other-bijuu-dont)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question @Wondercricket. It simply describes Naruto's current form. I want to know the reason for that.

Comment: as I said it is unique for kurama. and I believe that in the anime, someone stated 9tails is stronger that the others combined. @Beast

Comment: @Henjin Strength isn't a reason for being unable to use a complete transformation.

Comment: @Beast naruto's transformation is beyond others, the others can't use this transformation even if they wanted to so they are stuck with muscles and bones. and this is not a place for discussion

Answer (score 0):

I do not know for sure, but I think Kurama cannot appear in that statue because Naruto has half of his power. If we retrieve when Minato sealed the Kyuubi (on the early incident of the masked man, Obito), Minato sealed the Kyuubi twice: once in himself and another in Naruto.

Comment: please add Sources that would support your thoughts